# Recommended Access Modifiers for Testability of Wrapper Methods

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

One thing I have started doing in my tests is to wrap error messages and string concatenations into methods or variables to keep my tests robust should the error message contents change later.

So for example, I would refactor something like this:

```
try{
    someMethod();
}catch(e){
    throw new Error('error message.');
}
```

into this:

```
let errorMessage = 'error message';
...
try{
    someMethod();
}catch(e){
    throw new Error(errorMessage);
}
```

Or something similar if the error message contains a variable or something.

My question is what would be the best way to do this in Typescript? In Java I would have them be package-protected, but here it seems Jasmine does not have access to methods like this if they are protected. I have also tried making them static.

Is there preferred method for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one occasion where you can transfer some good practices from other languages.

If you create custom exceptions, you can test their type, rather than the strings - and you can also ensure uniformity of error messages.

This example looks a bit convoluted, but it should give you an idea (adapted from page 163-168 Pro Typescript).

1. A base `CustomException` class is created that implements the `Error` interface and will sit beneath any custom error types we want in our application.
2. An `InvalidDateException` is created to represent a particular class of error, this is the only place the error message string needs to be stored in the application.
3. You can now look at particular kinds of error as in the example catch statement where `instanceof` is used to check the type.
4. All your custom exceptions are compatible with the `Error` interface, which required `name` and `toString()`.

Code:

```
class CustomException implements Error {
    protected name = 'CustomException';

    constructor(public message: string) {
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
    }
}

class InvalidDateException extends CustomException {
    constructor(public date: Date) {
        super('The date supplied was not valid: ' + date.toISOString());
        this.name = 'InvalidDateException';
    }
}

try {
    throw new InvalidDateException(new Date());
} catch (ex) {
    if (ex instanceof InvalidDateException) {
        alert(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Related question: Would you suggest a similar method for string concatenation wrappers, such as those that compose a url based on one or more arguments?